# Projectname.exe has triggered a breakpoint and is non-consitent

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is my code in VS 2019. It stuck at `fclose(fp);` line with message:

> projectname.exe has triggered the breakpoint.

Without debugging it doesn't show the "finished reading" in the console. However, a couple of times earlier it does. I think the problem is with memory allocation somehow because sometimes it stops even before `fclose(fp)` line.

Two times it also created the "SmallSphere02_out.txt" file and write everything correctly. However, it is not consistent! Any idea?

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996) // disabling fopen and fscanf unsafe error [These are only MS required things not c++]


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE* fp;
FILE* fc;

struct vertices {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} verices1;

struct polygons {
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
} plygons1;


struct polyhedron {
    int numVertices;
    int numPolygons;

    //struct vertices vertices1;
    //struct polygons plygons1;

}polyhedron1;

void main()
{
    vertices* pv = (vertices*)malloc(polyhedron1.numVertices * sizeof(vertices));
    //printf("%p\n", pv);
    if (pv==NULL)
    {
        printf("Null pointer error of pv");
    }

    polygons* pp = (polygons*)malloc(polyhedron1.numPolygons * sizeof(polygons)+1000);
    if (pp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Null pointer error of pp");
    }


    // used for checking before pointers
    //float a, b, c;
    //int x, y, z;

    // Reading
    fp = fopen("SmallSphere02.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fp,"%d\n", &polyhedron1.numVertices); //66
    printf("%d\n", polyhedron1.numVertices);

    for (int i = 0; i < polyhedron1.numVertices; i++) // 66 vertices coordinates
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%f\t%f\t%f\n", &pv[i].x, &pv[i].y, &pv[i].z);
        printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", pv[i].x, pv[i].y, pv[i].z);
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &polyhedron1.numPolygons); //128
    printf("%d\n", polyhedron1.numPolygons);

    for (int i = 0; i < polyhedron1.numPolygons; i++) //128 polygons connectivity info
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d\t%d\t%d\n", &pp[i].n1, &pp[i].n2, &pp[i].n3);
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", pp[i].n1, pp[i].n2, pp[i].n3);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("Finished_Reading");


     //Writing
    fc = fopen("SmallSphere02_out.txt", "w");

    fprintf(fc, "%d\n", polyhedron1.numVertices); //66

    for (int i = 0; i < polyhedron1.numVertices; i++) // 66 vertices coordinates
    {
        fprintf(fc, "%f\t%f\t%f\n", pv[i].x, & pv[i].y, pv[i].z);
    }

    fprintf(fc, "%d\n", polyhedron1.numPolygons); //128


    for (int i = 0; i < polyhedron1.numPolygons; i++) //128 polygons connectivity info
    {
        fprintf(fc, "%d\t%d\t%d\n", pp[i].n1, pp[i].n2, pp[i].n3);
    }
    fclose(fc);

    printf("Finished_Writing"); // Checking Error

    //free(fp);
    free(pp);
    free(pv);

    printf("Finished_End"); // Checking Error

}
```

Comment: The first line: `malloc(polyhedron1.numVertices * sizeof(vertices));` Your variable (`polyhedron1.numVertices`) is not initialized. You don't assign it until later: `fscanf(fp,"%d\n", &polyhedron1.numVertices); //66`

Comment: You can't rely on buffered output messages being seen unless you ensure the buffer is flushed with `fflush(stdout)` or with a newline at the end of the message (most systems, I think).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Isn't `malloc` for such things that we are not aware of the size in advance? I even locate the definition of pointers after related `fscanf` line which reads that variable, it gives the same error.

Comment: in the cases of ptr `== NULL` succeeding you should abort the program, instead of carrying on to use the null pointer after printing a message

Comment: `malloc` can't see into the future. Your program just mallocs zero bytes .

Comment: "Isn't malloc for such things that we are not aware of the size in advance". By "in advance" it really means not known at compile time. But it needs to be known at the time that the `malloc` call runs.

Comment: One more time I put the related malloc after the related `fscanf` and it solved!. In an alternative question is it also possible to put malloc at the structures (vertices and polygons structures)?